# C/C++ pointers, ptr+1 = ptr +1 byte or ptr+1*sizeof(pointer_type)?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, gcc, memory-alignment

Having

```
any_type *ptr = (any_type*)malloc(sizeof(any_type)*size);
my_ptr = ptr+1;
memcpy(dst, my_ptr, sizeof(any_type));
```

Will my_ptr be pointed to 1 byte after ptr, or to `sizeof(any_type)` bytes after ptr? 
How alignment options may affect the answer? Is it different for signed/unsigned types?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is performed on the size of the static type[*] of the pointer, so it will effectively add `sizeof *ptr`. Alignment of the members will be accounted for in the size of the object, as the alignment of the type (padding at the end of the object).

```
struct test {
   int a;
   char b;
};
```

The size of `test` will not be 5 (assuming 32 bit ints), if the type is 4-byte aligned.

[*] Note that in C++ you can assign the address of a derived object to a base class, but pointer arithmetic will operate on the type of the *pointer*, not the actual objects:

```
struct base { int x; };
struct derived : base { int y; };
int main() {
   base * p = new derived[10];
   base * q = p+1;             // this does not point to the second `derived`!!!
}
```

Comment: +1 for illustrating the issues of pointer arithmetic related to base/derived conversions.

Answer (score 4):

1. sizeof(any_type) after ptr
2. malloc returns memory suitable for aligning any type of data
3. no difference between signed / unsigned

Answer (score 4):

The compiler will substitute that 1 to the appropriate number of bytes. All you have to do is to specify the number of *objects* you want to move to.

Answer (score 2):

When you see a pointer, try to forget that it has a scalar value. Think, instead, that the pointer is sort of a token that gives you access to an object that is stored in a continuous space (the memory). If `ptr` is a pointer that gives you access to an object at some (arbitrary) position, `ptr+1` and `ptr-1` will return pointers that give you access to its neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

For pointer arithmetic  to work it has to be pointed at sizeof(any_type) + the base address.